# Android Studio: where are listed all 'requires API X (min API is API Y)' warnings in Lint?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lint

I am trying to find in which category of the Lint errors/warnings are listed all the warnings like 'method requires API X (min is API Y)' in Lint ? Many categories (Lint -> correctness, etc...) and I can't find out where are can find all these 'min API' warnings (if possible grouped together)

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks) the list of lint warnings as of Android studio 2.3.

You can also observe the list from command line:

```
./lint --list
```

`lint` is located in `/sdk/tools/bin`.

I believe "min API" warnings are initiated with help of [`@RequiresApi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/RequiresApi.html) and [`@TargetApi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/TargetApi.html) annotations.